# Amplify Graphql subscription: Works in query editor, not in app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm trying to set up a basic graphQL subscription to update a list of messages whenever one is crated, based off the recipes in [Nader Dabit’s book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1492059897) and [in this Medium post](https://medium.com/@jaunesarmiento/building-a-chat-app-on-react-and-aws-amplify-part-2-b6a44158e7ac), and my subscription is just never firing in the client. What's strange is that in the query editor in Amplify’s Admin UI, the subscription fires as expected. In the app, however, it’s crickets. No errors, nothing.

As far as I can tell, the only thing unusual about my version is the typescript (and the `//@ts-ignore`’s that are required to account for the SDK’s lack of an Observable type).

Creating the message:

```
  const handleMessageSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(mutations.createMessage, {
          input: {
            authorID: userState.person.id,
            text: message,
            messageGroupID,
          },
        }),
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

The subscription:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onCreateMessage),
      // @ts-ignore
    ).subscribe({
      next: (event: any) => {
        console.log('new message:', event);
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });

    return () => {
      console.log('unsubscribing');
      // @ts-ignore
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [messages]);
```

Comment: NETWORK responses for both requests?

Comment: I see the response from the `createMessage` request, but I don't see any evidence of a response from the subscription request.

Comment: If I console out the subscription, it shows a state of "ready" if that means anything.

```_cleanup: ƒ ()
_observer:
error: error => { console.log(error); }
next: event => {…}
__proto__: Object
_queue: undefined
_state: "ready"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my imports.

Incorrect: import API from '@aws-amplify/api'

Correct: import { API } from '@aws-amplify'

The incorrect API worked just fine for other graphQL queries, but it was borking subscriptions.

I should also note that the failure was generating a `AWSAppSyncProvider.ts:204 Uncaught (in promise) undefined` error in the console, which I hadn't noticed earlier, though that didn't help much toward finding the solution.